# How to split lines on D3 geo map?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onclick, geometry, nodes

I'm struggling to re-create a function that when the user clicks on a line, 2 more appear either side of it. I've seen this function been done on a force layout graph seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/xhpg2ghn/3/ but I need help re-creating this function on a geo map. Can this be done?

Here is a JSfiddle to show what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/GarrettUK/ppkf3vqb/

**The way I've been trying to do this is with another click function the way I have the done the nodes show/hide function:**

```
var showAll = true;

    bnodes.on('dblclick', function(d, i) {
        showAll = !showAll;
        if (showAll) {
            showAllNodesAndLinks();
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the point =/ Could you explain with some pictures?

Comment: So the first link is to an example of line which when clicked... 2 more lines appear next to it. The second link is my current code and I put it in a JSFiddle becaus I need help re-creating the function from the first link?

Comment: Still not sure what you actually want to have. Sry.

Comment: Well I can't be any more clear... sry